# sum two time param on format 00:00:00.000 with javascript

Tags: javascript, time, format, milliseconds

I'm trying to sum some time-format param in format 00:00:00.000, is there some library or javascript function I could use easily? some function in moment.js that I miss?

the code expected is

```js
//variables time1 and time2 are in format 'hh:mm:ss.SSS' hour, minutes, seconds, milliseconds.

let time1='00:00:04.666';
let time2='00:00:09.335';

console.log(sum(time1,time2));

//expected output is '00:00:13.001'
```

Do you have some ideas that may help?

Comment: it is not clear what you are asking for, and the code doesn't do anything except return a set string.  post input and desired output, runnable working code that attempts to solve the problem, and a description of the purpose of the code.  My educated guess is that you want to sum up two `moment.duration` values to get the total hours minutes and seconds represented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using moment.duration and [moment-duration-format](https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format) plugin

```js
function sum(time1,time2){

    return moment.duration(time1).add(moment.duration(time2)).format('hh:mm:ss.SSS', {trim: false});
    //trim: false prevents trimming of zero values for large units

    //return informat = 'hh:mm:ss.SSS';

}

console.log(sum('23:11:11.111','11:12:23.456'))

let time1='00:00:04.666';
let time2='00:00:09.335';


let result=sum(time1,time2);
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.25.3/moment-with-locales.min.js" integrity="sha256-8d6kI5cQEwofkZmaPTRbKgyD70GN5mDpTYNP9YWhTlI=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-duration-format/2.3.2/moment-duration-format.js" integrity="sha256-V2cDGIwcTkie65pWb06MoExJ2IROrXOYZxEvrLj1rf0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add an example for sum times with format HH:mm:ss content in a object:

```
  object.sum.tempoTotaleInOre = 0;
    totInHours = 0;
    for (var key in preventivo.fase){
      totInHours += moment.duration().add(0,'hours').add(preventivo.fase[key].timeToSum,'minutes').add(0,'seconds');
      object.sum.tempoTotaleInOre = moment.duration(totInHours).format('HH:mm:ss',{ trim: false });        
    }
```

In this way iterated my object "preventivo.fase" and save in "totInHour" the sum. Finally inject that value into the property "object.sum.tempoTotaleInOre" with the correct formatting "HH:mm:ss"

Answer (score 1):

Try to follow these steps...

- convert both `time1` and `time2` to the timestamp format
- if *`time2>time1`*. `sum=time2+(time2-time1)` else: `sum=time1+(time1-time2)`
- convert `sum` to the format you need.

You could replace if/else statement in step 2 by using abs()

Comment: Could you be more explicit about your answer?

Comment: He means to convert from time format to milliseconds (since epoch ie: unix timestamp), sum them, and then convert back to time format.  Not sure why he's using time difference in step 2.

Comment: @user120242 yes you are right. 
 I am using time difference since I expect the timestamp format will be the ms since 1970... So if you don't do the subtraction (assuming year of time1 and time2 is 2020) the sum year will be 4040...